# How to get Action.Submit type: signin to trigger the popup window in Teams Bot Card

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I'm trying to use the adaptive card w/ the `signin` action but I can't seem to get the sign in popup window to display so that I can go through the sign in and authentication steps. I've followed the guides [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-actions?tabs=json#adaptive-cards-with-signin-action) and below is my JSON object for the card.

What am I doing wrong that's causing the popup screen not to popup?

```
{
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "version": "1.0",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "spacing": "none",
      "text": "Click below to authenticate",
      "isSubtle": false,
      "wrap": true
    }
  ],
  "actions": [
    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "title": "Click me for signin",
      "data": {
        "msteams": {
            "type": "signin",
            "value": "https://google.com"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Could you please share the console error which you are getting?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Rajeesh, did you solve it?

Comment: @Yunus you have tagged the wrong person. The question is asked by michael.

Answer (score 0):

'signin' action type initiates an OAuth flow that permits bots to connect with secure services. OAuth 2.0 is an open standard for authentication and authorization used by Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) and many other identity providers.

Here the user sends a message to the bot. The bot determines if the user needs to sign in and constructs the URL to the start page of the authentication flow, and sends a card to the user with a 'signin' action.
Please make sure the start page is in a domain that's on your validDomains list, and in the same domain as the post-login redirect page.
For more details follow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/auth-flow-bot